# GWT native drag & drop - DragStartEvent not firing on IE9

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-9, drag-and-drop

I have GWT 2.4.0 native drag and drop working with Chrome, Safari and Firefox. But on IE9, the drag start event does not fire and the cursor seems to go into a text selection mode.

Any ideas?

```
public class BaseFlowComponent extends Composite {

    public BaseFlowComponent() {
        this.initWidget(panel);

        this.addDomHandler(new DragStartHandler() { 
            public void onDragStart(DragStartEvent event) {
                event.setData("text", componentName);
                event.getDataTransfer().setDragImage(getElement(), 10, 10);
            }
        }, DragStartEvent.getType());

        this.getElement().setDraggable(Element.DRAGGABLE_TRUE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed since http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?spec=svn10138&r=10138.

GWT Team Test URL - http://gwt-cloudtasks.appspot.com

GWT Team Sample Code - http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/mobilewebapp/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/sample/mobilewebapp/client/desktop/DesktopTaskEditView.java

Ensure that you are running the sample code in the same browser and document mode in Hosted and Production mode. Also keep in mind GWT teams recommendation. https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideIE9

**Ensure IE9 is not running under some IE8/IE7 compatibility mode.**

For IE7 and IE8 the feature is disabled.
Reference - 
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?spec=svn10138&r=10138
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/0MkjaHsVfO4